# In SpringDataRest, How can i add custom logic when http request received

Tags: spring, http, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

As we know, 
In SpringDataRest, the Repository files are only used (not controllers) and we can use build-in methods for It.

My repository code is:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

I don't want to add custom methods and add my request processing logic there. I want some configuration or events overriding where i can process the HttpRequest handler, parse the token and check some data in token and based on that token i'll decide to either process that request or discard it with some error.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using spring security? If you want to do checks on a token it sounds like a spring security use-case.

Comment: Yes, token security is already implemented (Using ResourceServer etc). But i have to move security based on user roles further which i need to extract from the token i received.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use the antMatchers based on role like 6 in https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access to specific endpoints or operations with spring data rest and you are using spring security then you can use the [@PreAuthorize annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) with `hasRole`. To take an example from ['Securing Spring Data REST PreAuthorize'](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-spring-data-rest-with-preauthorize), you could have a CrudRepository like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public interface ParkrunCourseRepository extends CrudRepository<ParkrunCourse, Long> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    ParkrunCourse save(ParkrunCourse parkrunCourse);
}
```

Then only users with the admin role will be able to do posts to save these entities.

Comment: No friend, i don't have requirement for such ROLE based checks, I found solution here: https://gist.github.com/m-x-k/03a87252d2458010e1d69f37e35af6f1

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you were looking for more custom logic than just role-checks. Glad you found a solution in the HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can override/change URL in interceptor (preHandle) override method?

Comment: You mean like do a redirect? If so you could try response.sendRedirect https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-handler-interceptor

Comment: Hi friend, Yes your PreAuthorize approach seems better to me now, because i have to filter data based on customerIds (which i receive in JWT token). So i want to use @PostFilter but how i can call my custom code in it ? e.g. @PostFilter("myclass.HasAssignedCustomerData(filterObject, HttpServletRequest)")

Comment: Did you try getting the token out of the Authorization request header in the HandlerInterceptorAdapter approach?

Comment: I tried that approach but the project manager rejected it because it has no benefit over returning customer based data. because at that time there is no data and only request is receiving.

Comment: Then i realize that @PostFilter can be use to filter the resultant data but for that i need to call my custom logic in a method because of JWT token decoding and extracting the assigned customerIds and then filter the records based on only assigned customerIds

Comment: To do it with the PostFilter I guess you'd want to define a custom Spring expression

Comment: I have done it but @PostFilter is not working with paging (which is required in my case), see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3410 Also it seems not possible in future too see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3410#issuecomment-361043574 Do you have any other alternative for my case ?

Comment: As it happens I'm on the Activiti project and we add restrictions to data based on user's access level. We have a service layer that applies query restrictions (using either querydsl or the criteria api) and the calls to the repos go through the service layer.

Comment: yes friend, you are saying right, i'm also want to do that way but i'm too restricted here in terms of custom development. Any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053074/query-not-working-with-querydsl-predicate

Comment: You can take the predicate and enrich with extra restrictions in a service if you want to. https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-query-service/blob/7-201802-EA/activiti-cloud-services-query/activiti-cloud-services-query-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/cloud/services/query/rest/ProcessInstanceController.java#L100 takes the predicate and then https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-query-service/blob/7-201802-EA/activiti-cloud-services-query/activiti-cloud-services-query-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/cloud/services/security/SecurityPoliciesApplicationService.java#L34 enriches it

Comment: hi friend, many thanks for your support, i have found exactly what i was looking for here: https://github.com/yeldarxman/QueryDslPredicateModifier