# @Query not working with QueryDSL predicate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to use **@Query** over **QueryDSL**'s Overrided method, but when i'm doing that, it is ignoring my predicate which i'm providing e.g. http://localhost:8080/orders?state=Texas

The reason i need **@Query** is to apply security based on authentication principal e.g.

```
@Query("select o from Orders o where ?#{principal.username} = o.username")
```

**Complete code of repository:**

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order>{

    @Override
    @Query("select o from Orders o where ?#{principal.username} = o.username")
    Page<Order> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: You have only one predicate value? I see some errors in your code!

Comment: Hi friend, errors like ? no, i have multiple predicate, actually i have to provide that microservice to ui design team and they will use it based on their need and don't want me to write any fixed methods for their need, they need open hand on the API so they can query based on their requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make up your mind if you want a method implemented based on a provided query or based on a QueryDSL predicate. Spring Data doesn't combine them (as you found out).

In this case, I assume you have a good reason to use QueryDSL, therefore you should just add the principal based constraint to that predicate.

[This article shows how to access the principal](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) which you can use wherever you are constructing your Querydsl predicate.

Comment: Hi friend, Any sample code or details of how i can append/merge my principal in user (UI team) provided predicate ?

Comment: Actually it's about accessing principal, i want to merge my two works 
1. @Query("select o from Orders o where ?#{principal.username} = o.username")
2. Page<Order> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);

Means i want to apply user provided predicate on repository but in the same time apply/append my custom filter. e.g. they can only apply their filter(predicate) on the orders which are related to them (where username = principle.username), got my point ?

Answer (score 1):

With **QueryDSL** predicates you can create a class for create the query, using query builder

Like this:

```
    public class OrderPredicates {

    private OrderPredicates() {

    }

     public static Predicate findByCriteria(OrderSearchCriteria orderSearchCriteria) {

            QOrder order = QOrder.order;
            BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
           if(orderSearchCriteria.getUsername!=null){
            builder.or(order.username
                        .eq(orderSearchCriteria.getUsername));
           }

            //Some other predicates

            return builder;
        }
}
```

But if you want to extrat a list of Order by principal, you can create an ad-hoc query

First: Delete the override

Second: Define a query with an intuitive name

Third: use a parameter query

```
@Query("from Orders o where o.username = :username")
Page<Order> findAllByUser(@Param(value="username") String username, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: You are saying right my friend, but i have limitation of don't use any custom name method or fixed the no. of parameters. @Jens Schauder understood my situation.

Comment: @PaolaG what is this QOrder and how to create one from QueryDSL??

Comment: @KNDheeraj QOrder was created in automatic by using QueryDSL in repository interface, if I don't remember wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who also wants to embed some custom predicate in QueryDSL should look it once: https://github.com/yeldarxman/QueryDslPredicateModifier

Comment: Link is not accessible anymore.